# FileNameSizeDelimiteC must be constant

Tags: c#

The following code gives problem of "FileNameSizeDelimiteC must be constant", what's the problem?

```
public const char FileNameSizeDelimiterC = '|'; 
public const string FileNameSizeDelimiter = Char.ToString(FileNameSizeDelimiterC);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Char.ToString` is a function so must be called at runtime to get the value, this means you cannot store it in a [`const`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) value. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> A constant expression is an expression that can be **fully evaluated at compile time**. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a null reference.

You could however make it [`readonly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx):

```
public const char FileNameSizeDelimiterC = '|'; 
public readonly string FileNameSizeDelimiter = Char.ToString(FileNameSizeDelimiterC);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Char.ToString` is a method and so as far as the compiler is concerned it is not constant. The compiler will not run any code when it is compiling. Despite the fact that you or I may look at that and say "It will always be the same" the compiler can't. The reason is that it has no idea that `Char.ToString` will always return the same output for the same input. It could equally be something that is dependnant on config variables, time of day or any number of other things. And while the language developers could have included a way to mark methods in such a way that the compiler could do this they didn't so your consts really have to be const.

I assume in this case the code is sample code so you can't just use `"|"` which would seem to be the same thing?